# Will Crazy Redd appear in the same week as the fortune teller?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In Animal Crossing: New Leaf, can Crazy Redd come in the same week as the fortune teller?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can appear in the same week. They can't appear on the same day, though.

Well, there is a way to have both of them at once. Katrina, the fortune teller, opens a store in your Main Street. Then, she no longer needs your tent. Redd can show up then and Katrina will also be in your town. Technically.

However, if they're both in tents... the two tents use the same "space" so they don't appear together.  (Both tents appear in the [town square](http://www.thonky.com/animal-crossing-new-leaf/special-visitors/).) So only one can appear at a time. Redd is more likely to show than Katrina, who is not guaranteed to show every week. Redd shows up once a week, so you should see him every week without fail. That means Katrina *always* shows up in the same week as Redd.